# How acces QueryBuilder in Service container [Symfony - SonataBundle]

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

How do I use QueryBuilder in a service container?

**For exemple** :

```
services:
my.service:
    class: My\MyBundle\UserAdmin
    arguments: [ ~, My\MyBundle\Entity\User,~ ]
```

How can i access **QueryBuilder** for select only the Users loggeds (this is just a exemple) ? It is possible ?

Answer (score -3):

Injet doctrine entity manager to the service definition :

```
 arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

In the constructor of the service :

```
public function __constructor(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }
```

Comment: OP wants to create a query builder. How does your answer help him? at least write an example for a query builder.